# Why does the label value always display after refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a label that have value of text from a database.
I try to delete the data in the database and it works; the data has deleted. But why is the data that I have deleted still in the label? After I run the delete data the function I am doing `window.location.reload`. The label must be not have a value after the delete function runs. But in my code the label still has the value.

This my code

```js
$(document).on('click', '#delete', function(e) {
  var data = $("#form_md2").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    data: data,
    type: "post",
    url: "../php/stock_opname/op_delete.php",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Data: " + data);
    }
  });
  window.location.reload();
  clearInput();
});

$("form_input").submit(function() {
  return false;
});

function clearInput() {
  $("#form_input :input").each(function() {

    $('#p_awal').val('');
    $('#p_akhir').val('');


  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td width=1>
    <p align="left">Periode : <label id="p_awal" style="font-weight:normal"></label> s/d <label id="p_akhir" style="font-weight:normal"></label> </p>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The JavaScript code you've provided makes little sense when run on the HTML provided.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `value property` but `text()`.

instead of `$('#p_awal').val('');` use `$('#p_awal').text('');`

`<label>` doesn't output value through the value property.

Comment: i have try that.. try to change `.val` into `.text` before i made a question here. that label still have a value after refresh

Comment: i have put that..
you can look my jquery

Comment: it's missing in your post

Comment: your code is just wrong. Why do you need to refresh the page if you are using ajax?

Comment: when i use jquery it usually reload after do the function. but this i need to do that. the label is stuck

Answer (score 0):

try that, do you get any alert?

```
$.ajax({
    data: data,
    type: "post",
    url: "../php/stock_opname/op_delete.php",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#p_awal').text('');
        $('#p_akhir').text('');
        alert("Data: " + data);
    },
    error: function() {
       alert( "error" );
    }
  });
```

Comment: that's true too

Comment: i will try it w8

Comment: still same.. the label text still in there.

Comment: @Camille is that possible. the problem is from my table? i put that label into the html table

Comment: Should not have any impact where is your label, as long as `id` is set

Comment: do you see your alert poping after click on delete button?

Comment: nah... that's the alert not poping after i click the delete button

Comment: the other label is fine.. after deleting done they clear the text. just this label only have a text after the delete has done.

Comment: my 1st time get this eror

Answer (score 0):

try to put:

```
window.location.reload();
clearInput();
```

into:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert("Data: " + data);
}
```

result:

```
success: function(data) {
  alert("Data: " + data);
  window.location.reload();
  clearInput();
}
```

Comment: still same T_T.. the other label is fine. it clearing the text after deleting. but just this label only has that problem

Comment: So, it kinda doesnt make sense. If you are saying that the value is gone from DB but still on the page, it is either caching problem, or the way you populate your form.

Comment: all of my label is on one form and when i do deleting all of the data is gone from my DB. and on the page the other label in that form is gone too but just this one label is still on my page T_T